# Firebase not signing in existing users in android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am learning kotlin and came across a problem that using firebase, I was not able to sign in with userId that were already registered.
Whenever I try to sign in using registered email id , this code prints "trouble signing in".

```
        mAuth!!.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this){task ->
                    if(task.isSuccessful){
                        var currentUser = mAuth!!.currentUser
                        database.child("users").child(currentUser!!.uid).child("email").setValue(currentUser.email)
                        val intent = Intent(this,activity_login_2::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("uid",currentUser.uid)
                        this.startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Trouble signing in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
}
```

update-

This is what warning I get in Logcat whenever i try to login with existing user->

```
com.example.newu.cht W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
```

update-

I tried downgrading firebase version from 11.8.0 to 11.4.2 . But this did not help . It generates following errors:(

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could
 not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath':     Could
 not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath':      Could      not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2.
Open File
Show Details


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath':          Could 
not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2.
Open File
Show Details
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post any useful information to solve this problem (like the exception/s shown in the Logcat), you can start checking this two simple things:

1. Authentication -> Sign-In Method -> Email/Password ENABLED

[image]

2. Make sure your database rules are set properly
   (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart)

Comment: I checked both of these and they are OK. Please tell me the information you require to solve this . Thank you

Comment: The screenshot of the the Logcat when you run the app and try to SIgn-in (you can filter the Firebase related messages in the Logcat)

Comment: I have updated my question . No other changes are happening in logcat whet i try to sign in

Comment: Please check the update I have made. Downgrading firebase version did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try Downgrading the Firebase Version:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'  
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
```

Comment: Making the changes and trying to synch it gives the following error

Answer (score 0):

Add in your root-level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {  
         ...
            dependencies {
                        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' //google-services plugin
```

Then always in the root-level `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
     ...
        repositories {
                ...
                google() //Google's Maven repository
```

At the bottom of your app-leve `build.gradle` add:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Tried these and it did not help . Neither did it give any new error or warnings.